# Using the new Coinbase Key + Secret, I can't create a valid ADDRESS_SIGNATURE. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-php

I'm modifying the current Coinbase Php Gem to use the new Key+Secret API authentication.  I think I'm following their instructions perfectly, but I always get a response: `"error":"ACCESS_SIGNATURE does not validate"`

So far, I have:

- Confirmed that the signature is a lowercase hex hash
- Confirmed from the CB callback that my access key is accepted
- Confirmed from the CB callback that my nonce is valid
- Confirmed that my API Secret Key is correct

My test is a POST request to `https://coinbase.com/api/v1/buttons` with a few $params.  It worked using the old API method.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong under this new API method.

Here's the modified Coinbase_Rpc::request method:

```
public function request($method, $url, $params)
{
    if ($this->_apiKey === null) {
        throw new Coinbase_ApiException("Invalid API key", 500, "An invalid API key was provided.");
    }

    $url   = Coinbase::API_BASE . $url;
    $nonce = (int)(microtime(true) * 100);

    // Create query string
    $queryString = http_build_query($params);

    // Initialize CURL
    $curl     = curl_init();
    $curlOpts = array();

    // HTTP method
    $method = strtolower($method);
    if ($method == 'get') {
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = 1;
        $url .= "?" . $queryString;
    } else if ($method == 'post') {
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST]       = 1;
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $queryString;
    } else if ($method == 'delete') {
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = "DELETE";
        $url .= "?" . $queryString;
    } else if ($method == 'put') {
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = "PUT";
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]    = $queryString;
    }

    // Headers
    $headers = array(
        'User-Agent: CoinbasePHP/v1',
        'Accept: */*',
        'Connection: close',
        'Host: coinbase.com',
        'ACCESS_KEY: ' . $this->_apiKey,
        'ACCESS_NONCE: ' . $nonce,
        'ACCESS_SIGNATURE: ' . hash_hmac("sha256", $nonce . $url, $this->_apiSecret)
    );

    // CURL options
    $curlOpts[CURLOPT_URL]            = $url;
    $curlOpts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER]     = $headers;
    $curlOpts[CURLOPT_CAINFO]         = dirname(__FILE__) . '/ca-coinbase.crt';
    $curlOpts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;

    // Do request
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlOpts);
    $response = $this->_requestor->doCurlRequest($curl);

    // Decode response
    try {
        $json = json_decode($response['body']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Coinbase_ConnectionException("Invalid response body", $response['statusCode'], $response['body']);
    }
    if ($json === null) {
        throw new Coinbase_ApiException("Invalid response body", $response['statusCode'], $response['body']);
    }
    if (isset($json->error)) {
        throw new Coinbase_ApiException($json->error, $response['statusCode'], $response['body']);
    } else if (isset($json->errors)) {
        throw new Coinbase_ApiException(implode($json->errors, ', '), $response['statusCode'], $response['body']);
    }

    return $json;
}
```

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:  Though not modified above, it is fixed, and the full PHP Gem is available here: https://github.com/Luth/CoinbasePhpGem

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Here's what I ended up using:

```
<?php

function coinbaseRequest($what,$getOrPost,$parameters){

$apikey = "blahblahblah";
$apisecret = "blahblahblahblah";
$nonce = file_get_contents("nonce.txt") + 1;
file_put_contents("nonce.txt", $nonce, LOCK_EX);
$url = "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/" . $what . "?nonce=" . $nonce;

if($parameters != ""){
$parameters = http_build_query(json_decode($parameters), true);
}

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $nonce . $url . $parameters, $apisecret);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "ACCESS_KEY: " . $apikey,
        "ACCESS_NONCE: " . $nonce,
        "ACCESS_SIGNATURE: " . $signature
    )));

if($getOrPost == "post"){
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $parameters,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
));
}

$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $results;
}

//This is a POST example
coinbaseRequest("buttons", "post", 
    '{
    "button": {
    "name": "test",
    "price_string": "1.23",
    "price_currency_iso": "USD",
    "variable_price": true
    }
    }');


//This is a GET example. Note that the 3rd parameter is false.
coinbaseRequest("account/balance", "get", false);

?>
```

You should be able to just copy and paste this, replace `$apisecret` and `$apikey`, and you'll be ready to rock!

Comment: Thank you!  Using yours to work against, I found the part I was missing.  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS counts as a message body and must be included in the hash.  Duh.  :)  I'll post the new class to github in a few minutes.

Comment: Wooo! Yeah, this took me much longer to figure out than I'd care to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS need to be hashed too.  Complete Coinbase PHP Gem using Key + Secret authorization is here:

https://github.com/Luth/CoinbasePhpGem